# Select inputs from only one form

Tags: jquery

I have two forms on a page:

```
<form id="form2070" name="form2070" class="myform"></form>
<form id="formU2070" name="formU2070" class="myform"></form>
```

From the first form, I'd like to select all `input` fields. But if I do (sw is 2070, I checked):

```
var child = $('#form'+sw+' input');
```

it selects all the input-fields on the page, also from the second form. Am I doing something wrong (obviously, but what?)

Secondly, I only need the **type='text'** fields from the form. Currently I'm looping trough the array to find them:

```
$(child).each(function(){
  if( $(this).prop('type')=='text' ){
  //do something
  }
}
```

I tried using `$('#form1 input[type="text"]')` but that didn't work. Is there a way to filter them out in one statement?

**[update][solved]**
Problem solved. Altough both forms are propperly closed, I left one `<div>` inside the first form without the corresponding `</div>`, messing everything up.

Thanks everyone for the suggestions and the help!

Comment: fiddle would be much explanatory..

Comment: looks like you might have a form closing tag mismatch - check the form  using the browser element inspector to see whether both the forms closing tags are proper

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle to demonstrate this, because it looks correct.

Comment: `$('#form'+sw+' input[type="text"]')` should work correctly. Perhaps you didn't close your first form with `</form>`? Test for `('form').length` and see how many forms it finds on the page.

Comment: also to get the text fields only use the :text selector `var child = $('#form'+sw+' input:text');` - the attribute selector will fail if don't specify the type attribute explicitly

Comment: You should use `attr()` for non-boolean properties.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - `element.type` is a property

Comment: an easy way to check this is to add a css rule like `form{border: 1px solid red;}` and see which elements are within the bordered boxes

Comment: @Arun `var child = $('#form'+sw+' input:text');` did the trick. Now it selects propperly the fields from the first form. If I leave it out, it selects from both forms.

Comment: @Michel then there is some other problem because just adding the `:text` selector should not fix the first problem

Comment: @Michel did you add the css rule and checked what is happening?

Comment: @Arun It is strange. With `:text` child.length = 8, without 25. I'm gonna try to create a fiddle

Comment: @Michel it will be great if you can share the generate html

Comment: @Arun. Thanks for your advice, it was indeed something else. I'm very new to jQuery, so I tought it was my code.

Comment: @Michel post your ans below..and mark it as correct..and yes welcome to stack network

Comment: @adeneo `prop()` is most commonly used for boolean values like `checked` and `disabled`. `type` isn't a boolean value.

Comment: @Michel good.... in scenarios like this it is important to know the context of the code... so sharing the actual generated html will go a long way in getting help... The cases I gave above was from some of my own experiences where I has messed the closing tags which created some unpredictable behaviors

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - `prop()` for properties, `attr()` for attributes, makes sense ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var sw = 2070
  var child = $('#form'+sw+' input[type="text"]');
$(child).each(function(i){
    alert($('input:eq('+i+')').val());
});

});
```

Here is Demo url http://jsfiddle.net/Mkqb6/